# Geoserver build error

Tags: geoserver, development

i am getting a build error with mvn clean install on geoserver 2.2.x branch saying

```
Running org.geoserver.platform.exception.ExceptionLocalizeTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.02 sec
Running org.geoserver.platform.exception.GeoServerExceptionsTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0 sec
Running org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensionsTest
Oct 03, 2012 11:30:39 AM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions checkContext
SEVERE: Extension lookup occured, but ApplicationContext is unset.
Oct 03, 2012 11:30:39 AM org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions extensions
SEVERE: bean lookup error
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument "value" should not be null.
    at org.geotools.util.SoftValueHashMap.ensureNotNull(SoftValueHashMap.java:140)
    at org.geotools.util.SoftValueHashMap.put(SoftValueHashMap.java:281)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensions(GeoServerExtensions.java:113)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensions(GeoServerExtensions.java:150)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensions.extensions(GeoServerExtensions.java:239)
    at org.geoserver.platform.GeoServerExtensionsTest.testExtensionFilterByName(GeoServerExtensionsTest.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:164)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:130)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:120)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:230)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:225)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnitTestSet.execute(JUnitTestSet.java:96)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit3Provider.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit.JUnit3Provider.invoke(JUnit3Provider.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:110)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.invokeProvider(SurefireStarter.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireStarter.runSuitesInProcessWhenForked(SurefireStarter.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:68)
```

i tried building with both maven 2 and maven 3 on windows 7 with no chance.
complete output file is here
http://www.4shared.com/office/EvC5AB-w/out.html?

edit:
compilation fails with this message

```
Results :

Failed tests:   testDefaultStoredQuery(org.geoserver.wfs.v2_0.GetFeatureTest): expected:<[1]> but was:<[0]>

Tests run: 422, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] GeoServer ......................................... SUCCESS [0.831s]
[INFO] Core Platform Module .............................. SUCCESS [3.367s]
[INFO] Open Web Service Module ........................... SUCCESS [7.914s]
[INFO] Main Module ....................................... SUCCESS [4:11.637s]
[INFO] Web Feature Service Module ........................ FAILURE [5:37.378s]
[INFO] Web Coverage Service Module ....................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Map Service Module ............................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Web Modules ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Core UI Module .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Security UI Module ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Security Modules ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer JDBC Security Module .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer LDAP Security Module .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 1.0 Module ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Web Coverage Service 1.1 Module ................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoWebCache (GWC) Module .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST Support Module ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] REST Configuration Service Module ................. SKIPPED
[INFO] WMS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GWC UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WFS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Demoes Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] WCS UI Module ..................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Web Application ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Community Space ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] GeoServer Extensions .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 10:01.578s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Oct 03 11:40:36 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/67M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) on project wfs: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to C:\Users\bb\Documents\Projects\geoserver\src\wfs\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :wfs
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not seeing a failure here. Exceptions during tests are actually intended since many of the tests are testing error cases.

Comment: but compilation fails with this error message
Failed tests:   testDefaultStoredQuery(org.geoserver.wfs.v2_0.GetFeatureTest): expected:<[1]> but was:<[0]>

Answer (score 1):

I've also had units tests fail for elusive reasons (it was Main Module in my case).

While not an ideal solution; this worked for me (got successful install, haven't had any further strange behavior) and is suggested in [the docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/maven-guide/index.html):

> Often it is useful to skip unit tests when performing a build. Adding
>   the flag `-DskipTests` to the build command will only compile unit
>   tests, but not run them:
>   
> `mvn -DskipTests clean install`